# to hide parts of the image using pure javascript

Tags: javascript

I tried to make it by means of "area" concealment, but doesn't work. I need to replace one image with another of the same size on the timer. The image shall be replaced by substitution of the following leaking by identical rectangular parts. The first question with which there were difficulties and isn't possible to find the response, it how to break the image into rectangles which can be done invisible? Or prompt simpler method.

Comment: Which images will you use? are they static (always the same) images, or are they user-selected/dynamic?

Comment: Could you show us exactly what you have tried, or link to a demo? — and then take more time to describe the technique you're looking for?

Comment: Show us some code please and what you've tried. The solution is simple, however we won't help you if you don't help us :)

Comment: Im tried many static img tags with one map and display property selection. But its not working.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking  for CSS' [clip property](http://www.seifi.org/css/creating-thumbnails-using-the-css-clip-property.html)

Comment: For each such property the tag img is necessary ?